# transfer custom plotfunction to plotly

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash, portfolio

I am using the package [`riskfolio-lib`](https://riskfolio-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot.html). It allows you to do portfolio optimizations and plot all sorts of statistics for a portfolio of assets. As well as customized charts that I want to use in my `plotly` `dash` dashboard.

The Following Code produces a network chart. I am wondering how to get all necessary data from `ax` or anywhere else to reproduce the chart using `plotly` similiar as shown [here](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/) or [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/create-a-network-graph-in-python-8829e0ec6741)? As `get_xdata()` or `get_ydata()` don`t seem to work.

```
import yfinance as yf
import riskfolio as rp

# Date range
start = '2016-01-01'
end = '2019-12-30'

# Tickers of assets
tickers = ['JCI', 'TGT', 'CMCSA', 'CPB', 'MO', 'APA', 'MMC', 'JPM',
           'ZION', 'PSA', 'BAX', 'BMY', 'LUV', 'PCAR', 'TXT', 'TMO',
           'DE', 'MSFT', 'HPQ', 'SEE', 'VZ', 'CNP', 'NI', 'T', 'BA']
tickers.sort()

# Downloading the data
data = yf.download(tickers, start = start, end = end)
data = data.loc[:,('Adj Close', slice(None))]
data.columns = tickers
assets = data.pct_change().dropna()

ax = rp.plot_network(returns=assets, codependence="pearson",
                     linkage="ward", k=None, max_k=10,
                     alpha_tail=0.05, leaf_order=True,
                     kind='spring', ax=None)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you look at **riskfolio-lib** code on GitHub you can find the implementation of `plot_network()`.  With only a little refactoring you can remove **matplotlib** code and return `pos` (positions of nodes) and `G` **networkx** graph
- with these you have everything needed in the two links you referenced.  I've coded a function that will generate a **plotly** figure from these two inputs
- have generated **pandas** data frames from these inputs to then be able to use **plotly express** to generate figure
- take a look - it's maybe better that this gets contributed back to the project on GitHub as an issue/PR.  However I see that are none....

#### solution

```
import yfinance as yf
import riskfolio as rp

# Date range
start = "2016-01-01"
end = "2019-12-30"
tickers = ['JCI', 'TGT', 'CMCSA', 'CPB', 'MO', 'APA', 'MMC', 'JPM',
           'ZION', 'PSA', 'BAX', 'BMY', 'LUV', 'PCAR', 'TXT', 'TMO',
           'DE', 'MSFT', 'HPQ', 'SEE', 'VZ', 'CNP', 'NI', 'T', 'BA']  # fmt: skip
tickers.sort()

# Downloading the data
data = yf.download(tickers, start=start, end=end)
data = data.loc[:, ("Adj Close", slice(None))]
data.columns = tickers
assets = data.pct_change().dropna()

# matplotlib
ax = rp.plot_network(
    returns=assets,
    codependence="pearson",
    linkage="ward",
    k=None,
    max_k=10,
    alpha_tail=0.05,
    leaf_order=True,
    kind="spring",
    ax=None,
)

# plotly
plotly_network(
    *plot_network(
        returns=assets,
        codependence="pearson",
        linkage="ward",
        k=None,
        max_k=10,
        alpha_tail=0.05,
        leaf_order=True,
        kind="spring",
        ax=None,
    )
)
```

[image]

#### code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hr
import networkx as nx
import riskfolio.AuxFunctions as af
import plotly.express as px


def plot_network(
    returns,
    custom_cov=None,
    codependence="pearson",
    linkage="ward",
    k=None,
    max_k=10,
    bins_info="KN",
    alpha_tail=0.05,
    gs_threshold=0.5,
    leaf_order=True,
    kind="spring",
    seed=0,
    node_labels=True,
    node_size=1400,
    node_alpha=0.7,
    font_size=10,
    title="",
    height=8,
    width=10,
    ax=None,
):
    if not isinstance(returns, pd.DataFrame):
        raise ValueError("returns must be a DataFrame")

    labels = np.array(returns.columns.tolist())

    # Calculating codependence matrix and distance metric
    if codependence in {"pearson", "spearman", "kendall"}:
        codep = returns.corr(method=codependence)
        dist = np.sqrt(np.clip((1 - codep) / 2, a_min=0.0, a_max=1.0))
    elif codependence == "gerber1":
        codep = gs.gerber_cov_stat1(returns, threshold=gs_threshold)
        codep = af.cov2corr(codep)
        dist = np.sqrt(np.clip((1 - codep) / 2, a_min=0.0, a_max=1.0))
    elif codependence == "gerber2":
        codep = gs.gerber_cov_stat2(returns, threshold=gs_threshold)
        codep = af.cov2corr(codep)
        dist = np.sqrt(np.clip((1 - codep) / 2, a_min=0.0, a_max=1.0))
    elif codependence in {"abs_pearson", "abs_spearman", "abs_kendall"}:
        codep = np.abs(returns.corr(method=codependence[4:]))
        dist = np.sqrt(np.clip((1 - codep), a_min=0.0, a_max=1.0))
    elif codependence in {"distance"}:
        codep = af.dcorr_matrix(returns).astype(float)
        dist = np.sqrt(np.clip((1 - codep), a_min=0.0, a_max=1.0))
    elif codependence in {"mutual_info"}:
        codep = af.mutual_info_matrix(returns, bins_info).astype(float)
        dist = af.var_info_matrix(returns, bins_info).astype(float)
    elif codependence in {"tail"}:
        codep = af.ltdi_matrix(returns, alpha_tail).astype(float)
        dist = -np.log(codep)
    elif codependence in {"custom_cov"}:
        codep = af.cov2corr(custom_cov).astype(float)
        dist = np.sqrt(np.clip((1 - codep) / 2, a_min=0.0, a_max=1.0))

    # Hierarchical clustering
    dist = dist.to_numpy()
    dist = pd.DataFrame(dist, columns=codep.columns, index=codep.index)
    if linkage == "DBHT":
        # different choices for D, S give different outputs!
        D = dist.to_numpy()  # dissimilarity matrix
        if codependence in {"pearson", "spearman", "custom_cov"}:
            S = (1 - dist**2).to_numpy()
        else:
            S = codep.copy().to_numpy()  # similarity matrix
        (_, Rpm, _, _, _, clustering) = db.DBHTs(
            D, S, leaf_order=leaf_order
        )  # DBHT clustering
        MAdj = pd.DataFrame(Rpm, index=labels, columns=labels)
        G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(MAdj)
    else:
        p_dist = squareform(dist, checks=False)
        clustering = hr.linkage(p_dist, method=linkage, optimal_ordering=leaf_order)
        T = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(codep)  # create a graph G from a numpy matrix
        G = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(T)

    # optimal number of clusters
    if k is None:
        k = af.two_diff_gap_stat(codep, dist, clustering, max_k)

    clustering_inds = hr.fcluster(clustering, k, criterion="maxclust")
    clusters = {i: [] for i in range(min(clustering_inds), max(clustering_inds) + 1)}
    for i, v in enumerate(clustering_inds):
        clusters[v].append(labels[i])

    # Layout options
    node_options = {
        "node_size": node_size,
        "alpha": node_alpha,
    }
    font_options = {
        "font_size": font_size,
        "font_color": "k",
    }

    label_options = {"ec": "k", "fc": "white", "alpha": 0.7}

    if kind == "spring":
        pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=seed)
    elif kind == "planar":
        pos = nx.planar_layout(G)
    elif kind == "circular":
        pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    elif kind == "kamada":
        if codependence in {"pearson", "spearman"} and linkage != "DBHT":
            raise NameError(
                "kamada layout only works with positive codependence measures except when linkage is DBHT."
            )
        pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)

    return pos, G


def plotly_network(pos, G):
    df_n = (
        nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G)
        .stack()
        .loc[lambda s: s != 0]
        .groupby(level=0)
        .apply(
            lambda d: pd.DataFrame(
                {"linked": len(d), "info": [d.index.get_level_values(1).tolist()]}
            )
        )
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index()
    )

    df_n = df_n.join(
        df_n["index"].map(pos).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0: "x", 1: "y"})
    )

    cmap = [
        (r, c)
        for r, c in zip(
            np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 1, df_n["linked"].max()), 2)[1:],
            np.repeat(px.colors.qualitative.Set3, 2),
        )
    ]

    df_e = nx.to_pandas_edgelist(G)
    df_e = pd.concat(
        [
            pd.DataFrame(
                {
                    c: [pos[r[n]][i] for n in df_e.columns[:-1]] + [None]
                    for i, c in enumerate(list("xy"))
                }
            )
            for _, r in df_e.iterrows()
        ]
    )

    fig = px.line(df_e, x="x", y="y", color_discrete_sequence=["#888"])

    fig = fig.add_traces(
        px.scatter(
            df_n, x="x", y="y", color="linked", text="index", hover_data=["info"]
        )
        .update_traces(marker_size=37)
        .data
    )

    fig = fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            showgrid=False,
            zeroline=False,
            showticklabels=False,
            mirror=True,
            title={"text": ""},
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            showgrid=False,
            zeroline=False,
            showticklabels=False,
            mirror=True,
            title={"text": ""},
        ),
        coloraxis={"colorscale": cmap},
        margin={"t": 20, "b": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
        height=500,
        width=650,
    )

    return fig
```

Comment: Oh gread thanks a lot, didn't think of that! That's an awesome idea as I want to use more build-In plot functions, so now I know how to proceed! :)

Comment: fyi I have raised an enhancement request https://github.com/dcajasn/Riskfolio-Lib/issues/101  I'm happy to do the coding work on this,  haven't previously contributed to this project (or used it!).  May well be a good collaboration on other plot functions you note.